# Custom permission: All but site collection feature" & "manage site feature"

Tags: permissions

I have sharepoint group with custom permission.
I want this group to all access on site like admin except for "site collection feature" & "manage site feature". Is this possible?
Which access I have to uncheck from custom permission (initial admin access is granted)

Comment: Site collection features can only be managed by site collection administrators and if you are giving that access then you can't control that with permissions. So your question is really: "what permission level can I use to prevent a user from activating/deactivating features?"

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called Permission Levels.

Permission Levels allows you to specify on a granular level what a user can and cannot do.

Browse to `http://YoursiteUrl/_layouts/user.aspx` and click on "Permission Levels". Add a new one and select the permissions you want.

You can read more about the subject here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/sharepoint-server-help/edit-create-and-delete-permission-levels-HA101805381.aspx

Comment: User already said, he has custom permissions on a group, which states he knows what permission level it :-)

Comment: yes, i am using permission level only.
I have permission level "admin" which is duplicate of full control. Let me know which checkbox I have to uncheck so that user can have everything like full control except "site collection feature" and "manage site feature". User with admin access shoul not manupulate both.